# Remove email address from a string

Tags: php

I have a paragraph

> @test@gmail.com @test1@gmail.com  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
> the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
> industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
> book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
> electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
> popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
> containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
> publishing software like Aldus PageMaker

So I want to extract emails from this paragraph and send emails to extracted users with the rest of paragraph as message.so I extract emails and send message, but my issue is that still paragraph have email.
I did the following

```
 $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $comment, $matches);
    $email=implode("\n", $matches[0]);
  
    str_replace($email, '', $comment);
```

Expected message body=

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker

Comment: Why are you imploding the found email addresses with a line break, and then try to replace that? This would _only_ make sense, if your input text contained these emails separated by newlines in the first place. Your example input data does not look like it does though.

Comment: @CBroe That sounds like an answer, not a comment. :)

Comment: Are the email addresses always at the front of the paragraph?  I worry that your sample text may not accurately reflect the challenge of your real project text.  Do the email address always follow a `@`?  Do you want to remove this leading character?

Comment: What do you mean by "that still paragraph have email"?

Comment: Why does this question have two upvotes?  I don't find it to be very clear in explanation and the [mcve] seems a little undercooked.

Comment: The sample text seems to have `@` before every email address, but the output text strips away the `@` using some magic that is not represented in the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to explode paragraph like this to check if each element contain `@`and remote it to put it in `$arr_email`. I don't use regex.

```
$my_paragraph =  "@test@gmail.com @test1@gmail.com  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker"
$arr_email = [];
$arr_message = explode(" ", $my_paragraph);

foreach($arr_message as $key=>value) {

if(strpos($value, "@")  !== FALSE) {
  array_push($arr_email, $value);
  unset($arr_message[$key];
}

$my_paragraph = implode(" ", $arr_message);
```

Comment: @mickmackusa why? The explode is made on " " so the email extracted will be "@test@gmail.com" and "@test1@gmail.com".

Comment: I generally don't support this answer because it has an underwhelming sense of what is and what is not an email address.

Comment: @mickmackusa I try to help with code that will extract what the question ask for. If he want, he can add email validation instead of strpos. I'm here to help with hint, not to do all the job of thing that haven't been ask like email validation. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential workflow you could do:

1. Use a regular expression to find all email addresses
2. Replace all occurrences of the found email addresses with a blank

---

```
$paragraph = '@test@gmail.com @test1@gmail.com  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text...';
```

If the emails are always prefixed by an @ symbol, you could use this regex. It doesn't matter if the emails are in the beginning of the paragraph or somewhere else:

```
$matches = preg_match("/@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/", $paragraph);
```

The found emails are then available in the resulting matches array:

```
$emails = $matches[1];
```

You could then do some `str_replace` magic. It's lesser known that `str_replace` also accepts arrays to perform multiple replacements at once. So by passing all the emails ánd a replacement array equal in length, all emails get replaced in one go. By deliberately using `$matches[0]` to search for, we're also considering the prefixing @ symbol during the replacement operation.

```
$replacements = array_fill(0, count($emails), '');
$parsedParagraph = str_replace($matches[0], $replacements, $paragraph);
```

And afterwards we'll do some cleanup to remove double leftover spaces:

```
$parsedParagraph = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $parsedParagraph);
```

Comment: `\s\s+` is not refined.  There is a better way to express `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.  This question feels like a good candidate for `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 0):

**First extract the email address from string, then replace what you want.**

```
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
$str = str_replace($matches[0], '', $string);
$str = str_replace('@', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Please **edit** and explain what's going on here, explain how you solve the problem

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do a poor job of empowering/educating the OP and thousands of future researchers.